# Installing dlib fails with error "cmake configuration failed!"

Tags: python, cmake, pip, dlib

When I try to install dlib using `pip install dlib` it fails with this error:

```
CMake Warning at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/\
    cmake/data/share/cmake-3.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:765 (message):
            error: cmake configuration failed!

Command "/usr/local/bin/python -u -c "<stripped for brevity>" \
    install --record /tmp/pip-nSRKWl-record/install-record.txt \
    --single-version-externally-managed --compile" 
    failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nJyga7/dlib/
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be less personalized, so it's easier to find. I also stripped the standard invocation of setuptools as it's not relevant to the problem. Finally I reformatted to prevent horizontal scrolling, so it's easier to see where the problem is. Please add a few lines from the referenced FindBoost.cmake around line 765, as it will illustrate the cause. Good luck!

Comment: the questions is that when i install dlib in linux by pip install with the "error: cmake configuration failed!",what can i do without the error?I will be waiting for your reply